# Can't get localhost to connect to docker inside vagrant

Tags: go, docker, vagrant, docker-compose

I'm trying to build a local dev environment for GoLang.

My environment would consist of a VirtualBox VM using ubuntu and inside I'd use docker-compose to build out my different pieces.

All other pieces of my environment work, except for golang.

When I attempt to get a simple hello world HTTP response it get back "ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED" inside chrome.

My vagrant file looks like

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box =  "ubuntu/trusty64"

  port = 3000
  config.vm.hostname = "vagrant-docker-example"
  config.vm.network(:forwarded_port, guest: port, host: port)
  config.vm.network(:forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 8080)
  config.vm.network(:forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567)


  config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "apt-get update"
  config.vm.provision :docker
  config.vm.provision :docker_compose, env: { "PORT" => "#{port}" }, yml: ["/vagrant/docker-compose-base.yml","/vagrant/docker-compose.yml"], rebuild: true, project_name: "myproject", run: "always"
end
```

and my docker-compose file looks like

```
app:
  build: ./
  links:
    - redis
  ports:
    - "${PORT}:8080"

nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - 80:80
```

finally my docker file looks like

```
# Start from a Debian image with the latest version of Go installed
# and a workspace (GOPATH) configured at /go.
FROM golang

# Copy the local package files to the container's workspace.
ADD . $GOPATH/src/github.com/sinangedik/vagrant-docker-go-example

#Build
RUN go get github.com/tools/godep &&\
    cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/sinangedik/vagrant-docker-go-example &&\
    godep go build

#Give the ownership to daemon
RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon", "."]
USER daemon
#Set the port
ENV PORT 3000
# Document that the service listens on port 8080.
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["/go/src/github.com/sinangedik/vagrant-docker-go-example/vagrant-docker-go-example"]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

the Vagrant call is being run inside windows 10.

Comment: If you ssh into your Vagrant box, can you curl the go web service?

Comment: @R0MANARMY it either gives me a Recv failure: connection reset by peer or and empty reply from server unfortunately

Comment: What is the output of docker-compose logs app